# Making a array into a XML document

Tags: java, arrays, xml, dom

I'm attempting to take a 2 Dimensional array in java by adding it to an XML document using `DOM`.

I have an array that is *[100][7]*,

For an example line one is :

```
"Travis" "4" "4" "4" "4" "4" "B"
```

and i want to add it to a XML document with a root node called `<company>`

```
<Student>
     <name>Travis</name>
     <first>4</first>
     <second>4</second>
     <third>4</third>
     <adv>4</adv>
     <high>4</high>
     <class>B</class>
</Student>
```

How would one attempt this?

Comment: Please specify language, technology, anything useful to shrink the scope of this question....

Comment: Where the company node come into the picture? Is it root to Student?

Comment: One would use a DOM document and use its API to add elements to that document. Have you done any research about DOM and java?

Comment: , the comany node is root to student

Comment: i have done resherch into DOM and java, but i seem to have trobble adding nodes to an existing document.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code you can start with. I've written it on the fly so it might need twitches.

```
 // root elements
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

// Iterating rows
for( int i=0; i<100; i++){
    Element student = doc.createElement("student");    // create a new student
    rootElement.appendChild(student);                // append it to company

    Element name = doc.createElement("name");        // tag name
    name.appendChild( doc.createTextNode(array[i][0])) // value inside tag
    student.appendChild(name);                       // append name to student

    // .. repeat last 3 lines for other 6 tags (or create a function)
}
```

An easy to understand tutorial: [How to create XML file in java DOM](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/)

Comment: thanks for the tutorial ^-^, ill be sure to check it out fully when i next get a chance